# MySQL Query SELECT WHERE Statement not working after using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

I loaded .txt file with LOAD DATA function Into MySQL Database. All Queries were working till I Combined SELECT with WHERE statement which gave me Empty Set Instead of a five record file as output. Below is a description of the database

```
mysql> select * from Customers;
+------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
| CustomerID | CustomerName                           | ContactName            | Address                                           | City              | PostalCode  | Country       |
+------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|          1 | Alfreds Futterkiste                    | Maria Anders           | Obere Str. 57                                     | Berlin            | 12209       | Germany       |
|          2 | Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados     | Ana Trujillo           | Avda. de la Constitución 2222                     | México D.F.       | 5021        | Mexico        |
|          3 | Antonio Moreno Taquería                | Antonio Moreno         | Mataderos 2312                                    | México D.F.       | 5023        | Mexico        |
```

Here is the Error:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Well then country is not = mexico - perhaps some non printing characters or spaces have crept in. Try like instead of = with trim just in case.

Comment: seems some whitespace is there. Please try with trim or like once.

Comment: please i don't know about trim, can you suggest to me mysql syntax to use to do this trim

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: thanks. i will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: i have tried the trim but still have the same results. i tried to trim the whole table with the command below;

Comment: mysql> update Customers set CustomerName=trim(CustomerName),ContactName=trim(ContactName),Address=trim(Address),City=trim(City),PostalCode=trim(PostalCode),Country=trim(Country);

Comment: mysql> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: mysql> update Customers set ContactName=trim(ContactName);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 91  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Tried one command as above but still changes were not made

Comment: mysql> update Customers set CustomerName=trim(CustomerName),ContactName=trim(ContactName),Address=trim(Address),City=trim(City),PostalCode=trim(PostalCode),Country=trim(Country);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 91  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: same results with all the commands together

Comment: trim is just not removing the space

Comment: @PrinceAbokye try ` SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country like '%Mexico%';` or  try to copy your filed value in notepad may be there is extra white space or re-enter country name

Comment: It may be a different space than ASCII `0x20`.  `TRIM()` may not work on everything you cannot see with the naked eye.  Try manually changing the field in that database cell to exactly "Mexico" by hand.  And paste it into your code as pasted into that cell.  (in case of UNICODE differences in charset)

Comment: select * from Customers where Country='%Mexico%';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
still not working

Comment: the dataset is large so i can't do the changes manually. still need help. any ideas??